# How to add custom field to check in screen in TFS

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to add an extra field to the TFS check-in window?

I'm not searching for an extra field on the product backlog item, but a field for a certain value that i would upload to another app when the check-in occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using TFVC, the answer is yes, they're called [Check-In Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/configure-check-notes).

That just handles the "adding an extra field to the information gathered during source code check-in", however. Actually triggering a down-stream event and retrieving that value will require using service hooks and most likely the [REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#get-a-changeset) to retrieve the check-in note value from the changeset. I'm not sure if check-in notes are surfaced by the REST APIs or not -- if they're not, you'll end up having to use the old-school SOAP APIs.